# Returning a function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand why returning a function inside useEffect hook executes during the second time. For example:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => console.log("CHANGED!");
  }, [change]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setChange(true)}>CLICK</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The first time the component renders, 'CHANGED' is not being logged, but after I click the button, it does. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Per the React docs -  If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. The returned function will fire when the component unmounts.

Comment: My return function runs on page load so this makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

If you use console.log() inside of useEffect but not in the return block, then it will be executed AFTER rendering. Putting it into return block means, you want use it as a clean-up function, so it'll be executed before the component unmounts or right before the next scheduled effect's execution. However, in your case, for the very first time, you neither have a scheduled effect nor something mounted. That's why you see the string "CHANGED" only when you click on the button.